# How to reschedule messages with a specific time in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

My problem:

I pull off a message from a RabbitMQ-Queue. I try to process this message and realize that it can't be processed yet. So i would like to add it back to the queue and let it return only on a specific time + 5000ms. Unfortunately that is more challenging than i thought.

What i've tried:

RabbitMQ Dead Letter Attributes -> My issue here is, even though the manual says that the default exchange is binded to every queue it doesnt forward it according to the routing criteria. I've tried to add expires = "5000" and x-dead-letter-routing-key = "queuename" also "x-dead-letter-exchange = "" as the default exchange should work. The only part which works is the expires part. The message will disappear and go into the dark. This also occurs with the dead-letter-exchange beeing amq.direct including the binding on the targeted queue.

Open gaps for me:
Where i'm a bit left in the dark is if the receivers have to be dead letter queues and if i the dead letter queue is a basic queue with extended functionality. It is also not clear if those parameters (x-dead-letter..) are only for DLX Queues. I would like to do this delayed delivery persistent and purely via. the message attributes and not via. queue configurations (only if required).

I've searched on the web and checked many different dead-letter infos. Im trying to build a micro-service like architecture while using RabbitMQ as the delivery mechanism (i use processes which take their work from the queue and forward it). I would believe other people here have the same running already but i couldn't find any blogs about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to come to the conclusion that on the message level it is not possible.

I've created now for each queue which is in use a separate queue ("name.delayed") , where i can add the message with the argument "expiration" = 5000

The queue settings itself has to be a dead letter queue routing it to the queue "name"